# Why doesn’t my button work when it’s hidden?

Tags: javascript, button, element, hide, p5.js

I have some code here it is

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(1350, 715);
  var blueskin = createButton('BLUE')
  blueskin.mousePressed(changeblue)
  blueskin.position(100,400)
  blueskin.size(50,50)
  blueskin.style('display:none')
}
function changeblue(){
  playercolr='blue'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.1/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

When the button is not hidden it works perfectly but whenever I change it to hidden it stops working I looked some stuff up and aren’t buttons supposed to work even if hidden

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Is there an error or specific behavior you're seeing? (if so, please share it). What are you trying to achieve here? If the button is hidden, it can't be clicked with the mouse, so I'm not sure how you're expecting the user to trigger it when it's hidden.

Comment: `the button` - what button?

Answer (score 0):

Change the style from 'display:none' to 'visiblity: hidden' and then try it

visibility:hidden hides the element

display:none removes the element from the document

Comment: I tried this and clicking on the button still does not execute the function. I have a rect in the same position as the button so it acts as basically a different button icon then the normal.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`blueskin.style('display', 'none')`

per p5js documentation: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/style

The syntax should be style(property, value) rather than style(propertyAndValue)